# Obtain Bezier Path of CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, uibezierpath

`CALayer` objects have a property `accessibilityPath` which as stated is supposedly

> Returns the path of the element in screen coordinates.

Of course as expected this *does not* return the path of the layer.

Is there a way to access the physical path of a given `CALayer` that has already been created? For instance, how would you grab the path of a `UIButton`'s layer property once the button has been initialized?

**EDIT**

For reference, I am trying to detect whether a rotated button contains a point. The reason for the difficulty here is due to the fact that the buttons are drawn in a curved view...

My initial approach was to create bezier slices then pass them as a property to the button to check if the path contains the point. For whatever reason, there seems to be an ugly offset from the path and the button.

They are both added to the same view and use the same coordinates / values to determine their frame, but the registered path seems to be offset to the left from the actual drawn shape from the path. Below is an image of the shapes I have drawn. The green outline is where the path is drawn (and displayed....) where the red is approximately the area which registers as **inside** the path...

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding how the registered area is different.

If anyone has any ideas on **why** this offset would be occurring would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is a snippet of me adding the shapes. `self` in this case is simply a `UIView` added to a controller. it's frame is the full size of the controller which is `{0, height_of_device - controllerHeight, width_of_device, controllerHeight}

```
UIBezierPath *slicePath = UIBezierPath.new;

[slicePath moveToPoint:self.archedCenterRef];
[slicePath addArcWithCenter:self.archedCenterRef radius:outerShapeDiameter/2 startAngle:shapeStartAngle endAngle:shapeEndAngle clockwise:clockwise];
[slicePath addArcWithCenter:self.archedCenterRef radius:(outerShapeDiameter/2 - self.rowHeight) startAngle:shapeEndAngle endAngle:shapeStartAngle clockwise:!clockwise];
[slicePath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *sliceShape = CAShapeLayer.new;
sliceShape.path = slicePath.CGPath;
sliceShape.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.4].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:sliceShape];

...
...

button.hitTestPath = slicePath;
```

In a separate method in my button subclass to detect if it contains the point or not: (`self` here is the button of course)

```
...
if ([self.hitTestPath containsPoint:touchPosition]) {
    if (key.alpha > 0 && !key.isHidden) return YES;
    else return NO;
}
else return NO;
```

Comment: If your goal is “to detect whether a rotated button contains a point”, then please edit your question to include the code that performs that detection, because that's the likeliest place for you to have a bug.

Comment: Well I have no trouble detecting if a button contains a point, since rotations are taken into consideration automatically. I'll add my code to draw the shapes for you

Answer (score 2):

You completely missunderstood the property, this is for **assistive technology**, from the docs:

Excerpt:

"The default value of this property is nil. If no path is set, the accessibility frame rectangle is used to highlight the element.

When you specify a value for this property, the **assistive technology** uses the path object you specify (in addition to the accessibility frame, and not in place of it) to highlight the element."

You can only get the path from a CAShapeLayer, alls other CALayers don't need to be drawn with a path at all.

**Update to your update:**

I think the offset is due to a missing

UIView `convert(_ point: CGPoint, to view: UIView?)`

The point needs to be converted to the buttons coordinate systems.

Comment: Alright... well if you read my updated post *you* might understand my dilemma. I also provided the property as a reference to what I am looking for..not because I used this expecting it to actually give me the layers bounding path. +1 for at least posting something

Comment: Have a look at CALayer `hitTest(_:)` and UIView `hitTest(_:with:)` and `point(inside:with:)`. UIView functions will work even is the button is rotated. You need only a path if you need to hit test the path itself. Thx for the up vote!

Comment: I have already converted the point to the correct view before it is passed to my test :\

Comment: Mhhmm, I remember also having once trouble with it, and at the end it was a mistake in my conversion... I also had a strange 6 point offset. It should work, if the button is a subview you should have no problems with any offset...

Comment: You could also create your own UIBezierPath with the shape, dimension and position (location) and rotation transform of the squared button and hit test that, but I don't see any reason to do that, it should work without.

Comment: Testing with a little dot drawn for each point (each time) the path contains shows it is in fact offset by ~40pts lol.

Comment: I had once something similar at the end it was a missing conversion of one of my super views. Good luck!